# Service to redirect HTTP traffic on local server

Tags: linux, redhat, apache-2.4, oel

My scenario is an service listening on SSL port 443 for incoming SOAP and REST requests over the HTTPS protocol. Due to expanding configuration and the product can't handle a larger configuration we have now started two instances of the software, say instance A and B (either running on different IP's or Ports but still on the same machine).

I do have a list for all URL's that instance A are listening for. I want for example use Apache2 to have access to this list, if the Path of an incoming request is matching to any of the URL's in the list I want to forward on the traffic to instance A otherwise send it to instance B.

Is this possible to do in Apache2 or is there a better option? Could you show an configuration example for this?

Answer (score 0):

At first, your server instances aren't listening to URL's but to IP:Port combinations. You can configure apache2 by a list and reload the configuration. But what you request for is load-balancing in general.

By the way, nginx is much better in defining and balancing multiple instances.

See apache2.4 [mod-proxy-balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) or nginx [upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) documentation.